# How to apply for a permanent position at a company where I am already a contractor?

Tags: professionalism, hiring-process, new-job

I'm working as a contractor at a company that I'd like to convert to a permanent position.

There is a position open that I believe I'm a good fit for, however, the position would be in another subsidiary group within the company.

What is the proper protocol in dealing with this issue?

I would assume I would go to my current manager, then HR, but that may be a wrong assumption.  I also don't want to assume I could try to stay on permanently with my current position (which doesn't seem to be an option, not enough long term work) and then transfer later on to the other group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different companies have different procedures for these sorts of circumstances.

In my company, you would talk to your manager first, who would then guide you to the appropriate steps.

I'm assuming your contract isn't ending very soon, and just waiting for it to expire before applying for the permanent position isn't an option here? (Because that would be the simplest option by far, if applicable).

In my company, if I were the manager, you would come to me and say "Joe, I know my contract with you isn't over until X. But I really like working at this company, and I've just seen that there is a really interesting permanent position in the Y subsidiary. Would you mind if I take a shot at it?"

Assuming you were a good guy, I'd explain how you can go about it, and I'd probably shoot a note of recommendation to the hiring manager. If I knew the hiring manager personally, and I really liked you, I'd give her a call and explain why she should hire you right away.

If you weren't very good, I'd probably still tell you how to go about applying, but I wouldn't recommend you. And if the hiring manager asked me, I'd be honest about what kind of an employee I think you'd make.

There is a slight possibility that your leaving your contract early would cause a severe hardship for my projects. In that case, I'd suggest you not apply for the permanent position at that time. If you were really good, I'd promise to try and help you get a permanent position in the future.

Other companies, and other managers, do things differently. If you have a good relationship with your current manager, you could talk to her. Otherwise, you might want to chat with your co-workers to learn how this sort of things works in your company.

Good luck!

Comment: My official contract was a 6 month.  It's gone over through December of this year, but I'll have to start lining things up before mid November as that is generally the cut off point before hiring starts again in January.