# Is it okay to ask my boss for a permanent position in the company?

Tags: software-industry, consulting, israel

First of all I know that a similar type of [question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/14203/how-to-apply-for-a-permanent-position-at-a-company-where-i-am-already-a-contract) was asked here before but I think mine is somewhat different so let me start:

I have been working with this company for 2 years as a consultant, and nowadays I feel like my work is getting me more involved in the company. Firstly, they had asked me to maintain only a single project(that was our contract) but now I am actively maintaining more than 3 projects. Issue here is they don't have any open listing in the company for my job and I feel like by getting place as a permanent employee will give me better job security and might be a little less pay than what I am getting.

So will it be a wise thing to ask my boss for a permanent place in the company? And if so, how do I approach it?

Comment: When you say you're a "consultant", are you directly employed by the company you're looking to get a job with, or is a a third party involved?

Comment: coud you provide a country tag please? depending on country and fake employment laws, this could be a very wise move. Because when you are properly employed, this worry is off the table for both you and the company.

Comment: @PhilipKendall directly involved, no third party in-between.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I was thinking the same thing, but I had a fear of getting tag of over-ambitious

Comment: @Benjamin my employer is in Israel.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Got it! Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were I would say that you would like to clarify your situation in regards to the company. Something like

> " In the initial contract I was intended to only work on a single
> project. But currently I find myself devoting far more time and effort
> to you and for two additionnal projects. In light of this tendency I
> would like to know if I could join your organisation as a full time
> employee as I think this would be a beneficial change. You would not
> be bound by our initial contract and I could be more involved in your
> projects. This would also provide me with more security."

Add general thanks and say that you are open to negotiate and that you would greatly enjoy joining their organisation etc.

Comment: This looks like a good idea, thanks! Is there any way that it could backfire?

Comment: Hard to tell, if you lay down the fact, present it as a proposal without too much pressure and provide arguments in favor of this you could get a proposal or a status quo. If your client is pleased with you he has no reason to not consider this proposal. Though wording matters to maximise your chances.

Comment: I get it.. I would have to present it as a proposal maximizing both of our profits from the current setup.

Comment: Depending on how your contract is worded you may even put in that the added work falls outside the scope of the current contract. Then the two options given to the company need to be new contract or hire you to be an in house employee.

Answer (score -2):

**I would be cautious**

The lack of defined work for you could mean that your continued presence is the result of inertia and that nobody really planned for you to be there. I live in Calgary where contractors are all over the place and there are a lot of contractors here, some of who just sort of stuck around after their initial block of work was done and are now being dismissed to cut costs. In a time of cost cutting, people are taking a harder look at those costs.

I’ve known a couple of contractors who hung around a lot longer than intended simply because their projects ended and nobody really had plans for them after, but were never dealt with after that.

Determine if this company is looking at revenue/profit reductions and might be looking to cut costs. You might just end up reminding them that you are a contractor and be let go.

Comment: Interesting outlook.. and I think this is kind of a general thing going on at this time. But as of lately, my work in the company is getting increased and if I don't put in my hours company don't pay anything so is the "revenue/profit reduction" real for this situation as well?.

Comment: This sounds pretty good for the contractors who can keep collecting a paycheque while looking for better work.

Comment: @Malisbad except that is not what a lot of them did. They got comfortable instead.

Comment: @ED_DEVELOPER the question is whether it is getting deliberately increased or whether you are just around and someone who can do the work and the company is paying you on relative auto pilot. It also matters whether you can do the work cost efficiently.  I've seen 75 dollar an hour Java contractors be given a pile of CSS work. They had work to do, but not work appropriate for the cost.

Comment: I'm still failing to see what the downside for the contractor is. As far as I can tell, you're looking out for the interests of the company. If a contractor sits around and gets comfortable while collecting a cheque, it might suck when they get the axe, but pretty sweet up until that point.